# Laravel 5.2 - Sweet Alert confirmation box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5, sweetalert

I have Categories listed in a view. A delete category button is also there in the view which does work and deletes the category when clicked.

What I want to do is before deleting a category, a sweet alert dialog to pop up and ask for confirmation. If confirmed, it should go to the defined route and delete the category.

The delete link is defined like this:

`<a id="delete-btn" href="{{ route('admin.categories.destroy', $category->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>`

and the script is defined like this:

```
<script> 
    $(document).on('click', '#delete-btn', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);
        swal({
            title: "Confirm Delete",
            text: "Are you sure to delete this category?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: true
         },
         function(isConfirm){
             if(isConfirm){
                window.location = link.attr('href');
             }
             else{
                swal("cancelled","Category deletion Cancelled", "error");
             }
         });
    });
</script>
```

However, when I click the delete button it deletes the category, but the sweet alert message doesn't show up.

The route is defined as following:

```
Route::get('/categories/destroy/{category}', [
    'uses' => 'CategoriesController@destroy',
    'as' => 'admin.categories.destroy',
]);
```

and the controller function is defined as:

```
public function destroy(Category $category) 
{

    $category->delete();

    //this alert is working fine. however, the confirmation alert should appear 
    //before this one, which doesn't
    Alert::success('Category deleted successfully', 'Success')->persistent("Close");

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var deleter = {

        linkSelector : "a#delete-btn",

        init: function() {
            $(this.linkSelector).on('click', {self:this}, this.handleClick);
        },

        handleClick: function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var self = event.data.self;
            var link = $(this);

            swal({
                title: "Confirm Delete",
                text: "Are you sure to delete this category?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                closeOnConfirm: true
            },
            function(isConfirm){
                if(isConfirm){
                    window.location = link.attr('href');
                }
                else{
                    swal("cancelled", "Category deletion Cancelled", "error");
                }
            });

        },
    };

    deleter.init();
</script>
```

**EDIT**: From your comment at @kalyan-singh-rathore's answer, I think you're not properly injecting the script in your blade template. If you're extending a base layout, make sure you've included the script or yielded it from a child layout.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Write anchor in below way.

```
 <a href="#" customParam="URL">Delete</a>
```

Now in URL select change href to customParam.

```
function (isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
        window.location = link.attr('customParam');
    } else {
        swal("cancelled", "Category deletion Cancelled", "error");
    }
}
```

Basically in your case both href and event lisner are on click.

Comment: Didn't work. This time even categories are not getting deleted.

Comment: Once debug and check call in jquery event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it worked out for me :)

```
    document.querySelector('#promote').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        let form = this;

        e.preventDefault(); // <--- prevent form from submitting

        swal({
            title: "Promote Students",
            text: "Are you sure you want to proceed!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            // confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, I am sure!',
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false,
            dangerMode: true,
        }).then((willPromote) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (willPromote.value) {
                form.submit(); // <--- submit form programmatically
            } else {
                swal("Cancelled", "No students have been promoted :)", "error");
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```